# Live markup editor with freehand drawing/Whiteboard with markup text

Tags: drawing, markdown

I'm looking for a Linux, Windows or browser-based editor that supports

- live rendering of marked up text, ideally Markdown
- freehand drawing
- ideally but not necessarly MathJax.

What I've found so far:

- [Typora](https://typora.io/) is a great live Markdown editor but
  unfortunately doesn't have freehand drawing.
- [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/) includes MathJax, text mode and
  drawing areas, but I have to click buttons to format text, and
  switching between different modes is somewhat cumbersome.